# Find mismatch on 2nd column between 2 text files

Tags: perl, text, comparison, mismatch

I have these 2 text files and I would like to find any mismatch on 2nd column between files. The mismatch to be identified is based on type of `F ,P and N` regardless which lines they occur. I have 1F, 3P in first file while 2P,1N and 1F in second file. When do comparison, both files should have equal occurrence of type 1F, 3P and 1N.

Text1:

```
f0x11 F
f0x34 P
drx99 
dex67 P
edx43 P
sdx33
```

Text2:

```
1 P
2 N
4 
5 F
6 
7 P
```

Expected Output:

```
Text 1 has missing type of N
Text 2 has missing type of P
```

What I have tried so far does not produce desired output.

code:

```
use strict;
my %ref_data;
my %ref_data2;
open my $fh, '<', 'Text1' or die "Could not open file to read:$!";
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
    my ($res, $type) = split;
    if (defined $type){
             $ref_data{$type} = "$type"; 
            }           
 }
our ($data,$data2);
open $fh, '<', 'Text2' or die "Could not open file to read:$!";
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
 my ($res, $type) = split;
    if (defined $type){
                $ref_data2{$type}= "$type";
                $data2= $ref_data2{$type};
                $data = $ref_data{$type};
                print "File 2 has missing type of $type\n" unless $data;
         }
  }
foreach ($data){
print "File 1 has missing type of $_\n" if $data ne $data2;
}
```

Comment: Please do advise me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how you get your expected output above from your example inputs. Both of your input files have one F, just on different lines: why does your output say only one of them has a "missing type of F"?

Comment: @llmari it was typo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored your code where you seem to be duplicating the same behavior.

The output isn't to spec, but should be clear enough for you to understand and finish up yourself.

I added a `close $fh;` and `use warnings;` as well

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#run
my %max; # hash of combined data
my $file_data_1 = parse_file_into_hash("text1", \%max);
my $file_data_2 = parse_file_into_hash("text2", \%max);
diff_hashes(\%max, $file_data_1, $file_data_2);

# diff_hashes($max, $h1, $h2)
#
# diffs 2 hash refs against a combined $max hash and prints results
sub diff_hashes {
    my ($max, $h1, $h2) = @_;

    # TODO - do all the comparisios and some error checking (if keys exist etc...) here
    for my $key (keys %$max) {
        print "max/combined: $key = $max->{$key}\n";

        my $h1_print = exists $h1->{$key} ? $h1->{$key} : "0";
        my $h2_print = exists $h2->{$key} ? $h2->{$key} : "0";

        print "h1: $key = $h1_print\n";
        print "h2: $key = $h2_print\n";
    }
}

# parse_file_into_hash($file, $max)
#
# $max is a hash reference (passed by reference) so you can count occurences over 
# multiple files...
# returns reference of hash ( $line_number => $data_value )
sub parse_file_into_hash {
    my ($file, $max) = @_;
    my %ref_data;

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Could not open file to read:$!";
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        my ($res, $type) = split /\s+/, $line;

        if ($type) {
            $ref_data{$type}++;

            if (!exists $max->{$type} || $ref_data{$type} > $max->{$type}) {
                $max->{$type} = $ref_data{$type};
            }
        }
    }
    close $fh;

    return \%ref_data;
}
```

Output ran against your example files:

```
$ ./example.pl
max/combined: F = 1
h1: F = 1
h2: F = 1
max/combined: N = 1
h1: N = 0
h2: N = 1
max/combined: P = 3
h1: P = 3
h2: P = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. To make it clear, I would like to check whether type in 2nd column of text 1 is equal to the type in another file. I have `1F, 3P` in first file while `2P,1N and 1F`in second file. When comparison, both files should have equal number of type `1F, 3P and 1N` regardless the order or row it is. Therefore, message `File 1 has missing type of N,P` and `File 2 has missing type of P`.

Comment: @annel - I've changed my example to do what you want. I haven't done the output the way you want on purpose. You should be able to do this part yourself. This seems like a homework assignment to me...

Answer (score 3):

You appear to want to keep track of how many times the values in Column 2 occur within each file -- for example, in a comment you write, "*I have 1F, 3P in first file while 2P,1N and 1Fin second file*". If that's the case, **you need a better data structure**.

Specifically, one that counts occurrences of the values in Column 2, and you need those counts to be tracked separately for each file. That suggests a hash-of-hashes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Example usage:
# perl YOUR_SCRIPT.pl a.txt b.txt
my @files = @ARGV;   

# Count the values in Column 2, organizing the tallies like this:
# $tallies{COL_2}{FILE_NAME} = N
my %tallies;
while (<>) {
    my @cols = split;
    $tallies{$cols[1]}{$ARGV} ++ if @cols > 1;
}

# Print discrepancies.
for my $c2 (keys %tallies) {
    my @t = map { $tallies{$c2}{$_} || 0 } @files;
    next if $t[0] == $t[1];
    print "$c2: $files[0] has $t[0]; $files[1] has $t[1]\n";
}
```

Example output:

```
N: a.txt has 0; b.txt has 1
P: a.txt has 3; b.txt has 2
```

Also worth noting: this code does not have to open any files explicitly, and file names are not hard-coded in the program. Instead, we pass input file names as command-line arguments, get those arguments via `@ARGV`, process lines in those files via `<>`, and know which file we're currently processing via `$ARGV`.